# BindingFlags.OptionalParameterBinding varying behaviour in different frameworks. Bug in .NET?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5, .net-4.5, activator

I've tried to force `Activator.CreateInstance` to use a constructor with default parameters.

I've found this suggestion, repeated few times on SO (first comment) http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521722/system-activator-createinstance-throws-system-missingmethodexception-with-constructor-containing-an-optional-parameter

I wanted to run it on Mono and it didn't work, throwing a `MissingMethodException`. Before filing a bug I've made an experiment on .NET 4.5:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new A();
        Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(A),
            BindingFlags.CreateInstance 
            | BindingFlags.Public 
            | BindingFlags.Instance
            | BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding,
            null, new Object[] {Type.Missing}, null);
    }
}
class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First");
    }
    public A(int i = 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second");
    }
}
```

Of course, the result was predictable:

```
First
Second
```

Then I've tried to remove the `Type.Missing` parameter to see what happens, hoping to find a way to invoke a constructor with varying number of default parameters.

I was flabbergasted to see that nothing changed! By passing `new Object[]{}` I've expected:

```
First
First
```

Wondering what does Type.Missing do, and, by golly!, why is it mentioned in the examples over the Internet, I've changed the framework.

On .NET 4.0 it was the same, BUT on .NET 3.5 the result was

```
First
First
```

This seems very odd. Are there any documented reasons of such behaviour?

What is the proper way to call a constructor with possibly many optional parameters?

Comment: I don't think you can make this fly, optional parameters are a compiler implementation detail.  Check the MSDN article for BindingFlags and note that it says that you cannot use OptionalParamBinding this way.

Comment: Yes, that was my concern in the first place. Only this comment I've linked, signed by Microsoft, led me to thinking there is a bug in documentation. It's very peculiar though, a member of a widely used Enum that should only be used in one specific case. Looks like a very strange design choice to me, to be honest. On the other hand, I understand the special character of optional parameters. It's only that when I'm given a compiler acceptable option, I try to use it ;-) Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Optional parameters are part of the CLR starting with .NET 1.0. Only C# did not have them.

Comment: @Hans Why cannot one use it this way?